# how to take this integral to calculate heat equation solution

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals, heat-equation

$$u_t-4u_{xx}=0$$
$$u(x,0)=3e^{-2x^2}+2$$
$$-\infty<x<\infty, t>0$$
I know the general formula for heat equations for the range of x as above, is:
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{(4k\pi t)^\frac{1}{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty}e^{\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4kt}}.\phi(y)dy$$
so here my $k=4$ and my $\phi=3e^{-2x^2}+2$
.
then I have to solve $$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{4(\pi t)^\frac{1}{2}}(\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty}e^{\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4kt}}.3e^{-2y^2}dy+\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty}e^{\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4kt}}.2dy)$$
then the second integral is zero. But I have difficulties to calculate the first therm of integral:$$\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty}e^{\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4kt}}.3e^{-2y^2}dy$$
I appreaciate any help with that.

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty}e^{\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4kt}}.3e^{-2y^2}dy = 3\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty}e^{\frac{-x^2-y^2+2xy}{4kt} -2y^2}.dy$$

$$=3e^{\frac{-x^2}{4kt}}\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty}e^{\frac{-y^2+2xy-8kty^2}{4kt}}.$$ Now try completing the square for $y$ in the exponent!